# Remove strings from date column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where different strings are located in date columns. My sample data frame is as follows:

```
df=[["1/5/2020 Yes", "5/9/2020 String",2,6],["1/8/2020 No","5/8/2020 sponge",8,9],["8/9/2020 Spine","5/8/2020 spike",8,9]]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns=["Start","Finish","x1","x2"]

Start              Finish          x1   X2
1/5/2020 Yes    5/9/2020 String     2   6
1/8/2020 No     5/8/2020 sponge     8   9
8/9/2020 Spine  5/8/2020 spike      8   9
```

Now, I want to remove the strings from date columns. I want a generalized form of solution to remove any string that is attached in the start and finish columns. Can anyone help me to solve this please?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you trie anything, done any research? This is also far too broad. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, using regex as well:

```
df.Start = df.Start.str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]','').str.strip()
df.Finish = df.Finish.str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]','').str.strip()

    Start         Finish    x1  x2
0   1/5/2020    5/9/2020    2   6
1   1/8/2020    5/8/2020    8   9
2   8/9/2020    5/8/2020    8   9
```

Answer (score 3):

I think we can try `dateutil`

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
df.Start.apply(dparser.parse,fuzzy=True)
0   2020-01-05
1   2020-01-08
2   2020-08-09
Name: Start, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression combined with `extract` method

```
df.Start = df.Start.str.extract('([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)')
df.Finish = df.Finish.str.extract('([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)')

df.head()

#   Start       Finish      x1  x2
# 0 1/5/2020    5/9/2020    2   6
# 1 1/8/2020    5/8/2020    8   9
# 2 8/9/2020    5/8/2020    8   9
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try to split on space and extract first element if date is going occur in start

```
In [103]: def extract_date(x):
     ...:     return x.split(" ")[0]
     ...:

In [104]: extract_date("1/5/2020 Yes")
Out[104]: '1/5/2020'

In [105]: df['Start'] = df['Start'].apply(extract_date)

In [106]: df['Finish'] = df['Finish'].apply(extract_date)

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
      Start    Finish  x1  x2
0  1/5/2020  5/9/2020   2   6
1  1/8/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
2  8/9/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
```

Based on @phillyclause89 suggestion

```
df['Start'] = df['Start'].str.split(" ").str[0]
df['Finish'] = df['Finish'].str.split(" ").str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
keys = ['Start', 'Finish']
for k in keys:
     for e, i in enumerate(df[k]):
         a = i.split()
         df[k][e] = a[0]

df
      Start    Finish  x1  x2
0  1/5/2020  5/9/2020   2   6
1  1/8/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
2  8/9/2020  5/8/2020   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit roundabout, but here's an example of running it with panndas only.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df['Start'].str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1).drop('Start', axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={0:'Start', 1:'del_1'}, inplace=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df2['Finish'].str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1).drop('Finish', axis=1)
df3.rename(columns={0:'Finish', 1:'del_2'}, inplace=True)
df3 = df3.drop(['del_1','del_2'], axis=1)
df3 = df3.iloc[:,[3,2,0,1]]
```